# PHP jquery image effect on mouseover

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, gdlib

I want to make my original image to portrait when I mouse over on an image. Can anyone please tell me how to do this? I want to open whole image on mouseover with portrait effect.

Comment: Do you have the portrait image available or do you want to do that with css?

Comment: I want to create portrait from original image. I dont have portrait image available.

Comment: What do you mean by "original" image? Can u give an example or website address where it is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use css [`transform`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp).

```
.main:hover img {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

example [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ce1c6dah/)

Answer (score 1):

You should use jQuery to this with method mouseover() and mouseout(), The rotate attribute doesn't let your picture horizontally.
Here my JSfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/gLj8n9s6/

CSS

```
#main {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#img {
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="main">
    <img id="img" src="http://s13.postimg.org/m3yqyd7zb/windows_xp_bliss_wide.jpg" />
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('#main').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).animate({width : '200px'});
});
$('#main').mouseout(function() {
    $(this).animate({width : '300px'});
});
```

Or KISS by doing this in pure CSS without the animate method in jQuery

Answer (score 0):

On mouse over of the image you can open a `DIV` with some z-index and then place the image and do some css styling to make that portrait effect. You can make the popup DIV size as per the image size as well. Check [this](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/) for css property. I think this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty straight forward using css3

```
img:hover {
 transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

have a look at css transform http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp

edit : actually that might not be what you want. The image would transform back to landscape on mouseout